# How to add instances of classes to make a library for user accesses in python?

Tags: python, class

Let's say I had a class like this,

```
class Ball(object):
    def _init_(self, id=1, name="", size=0):
         self.id = id
         self.symbol = symbol
         self.size = size
```

And an instance like this... (I think the syntax may have errors?)

```
Basketball = Ball()
Basketball.name = "Basketball"
Basketball.id = 2
Basketball.size = 100
```

Lets say I had created more instances like beach ball and baseball, How could I put them in some kind of library representing the class so a user can request 'Ball' and then type the name of a instance of the class ball and receive it.
It would go Something like this for better explanation...

- Open Ball
- Input A Name
- Get as an Output, any properties of that instance.  All I stored into a library.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code so far would generally be written:

```
basketball = Ball(2, "Basketball", 100)
```

Secondly, you probably want something like:

```
balls = {"basketball": Ball(2, "Basketball", 100), ...}
```

Then you can access each ball:

```
basketball = balls["basketball"]
```

Alternatively, you could sub-class `Ball` if each individual ball will have different properties:

```
class Basketball(Ball):

    def __init__(self, id, size):
        super(self, Basketball).__init__(id, "Basketball", size)
```

Comment: Yes each will have different properties

Comment: If they will have additional attributes and/or methods to the basic `Ball`, subclassing is the way to go.

Comment: But how would I specify the id, size, etc. that is specific to the basketball?

Comment: You can set the default arguments for `Basketball.__init__`, or even not allow arguments, then pass them to `Ball` using `super`.

Comment: Further more, do I have to put all properties into a list, or can it just follow with self. whatever the properties are.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
balls = {}

ball_types = [('Basketball', 2, 100), ('Baseball', 7, 200)]

for name, ball_id, sz in ball_types:
    my_balls[name] = Ball(name=name, id=ball_id, size=sz)

# get a ball
print 'Basketball -> %s' % (balls['Basketball'])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this could be to store a dictionary that stores the information of all the different Ball Params

```
{
   'BasketBall': {
            'Name': 'BasketBall',
            'Size': 100
       },
   'Baseball': {...}
}
```

And then write a function that returns an object based on the request and uses the dictionary to instantiate the class. Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: jonsharpe has a better explanation